# Publish Universal Package using Release Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When I attempt to publish a universal package using Azure DevOps release pipeline it says it succeeds however I am unable to see the package.

What I want to do is use my build pipeline to build an MSI of my application save it as an artifact which works fine.

I then want my release pipeline to publish it is a universal package but it doesn't upload it.

Note I can use a copy files task to copy it so I know the files are there.

Settings

```
Path: **\App.Logic-Server.Setup.msi
Feed Location: This Account/Collection
package name: app-logic-setup
version: Next patch
Verbosity: Trace
```

Actual Results

```
- (node:110032) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Failed to find api location for area: clienttools id: 187ec90d-dd1e-4ec6-8c57-937d979261e5
- SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
- ##[section]Finishing: Universal publish
```

Comment: Can you share your release pipeline?

Comment: Which are you using? VSTS? Or TFS? If TFS, which version of TFS are you using? As I know, TFS does not support in Server 2019 now, only in DevOps Services.